# First Option not get displayed in select field

Tags: javascript, html, select, field

- Following is the html code that i am using.
- these divisions should be displayed on change of select field.
- By selecting Long Question Option we didn't get any response so please help me

```js
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === "1"){
        $("#long_question").show();
    } else {
        $("#long_question").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "2"){
        $("#short_question").show();
    } else {
        $("#short_question").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "3"){
        $("#mcq").show();
    } else {
        $("#mcq").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "4"){
        $("#reasons").show();
    } else {
        $("#reasons").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "5"){
        $("#matching_questions").show();
    } else {
        $("#long_question").hide();
    }
 
});
```

```css
#long_question, #short_question, #mcq, #reasons, #matching_questions {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<select class="form-control" id='purpose' required>
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">Long Questions</option>
    <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
    <option value="3">MCQ</option>
    <option value="4">Reasons</option>
    <option value="5">Matching Questions</option>
</select>
</div>

 - End of Select Field Division
 - Following are the division which should be displayed on click event
<form id="long_question"> // this block is not displayed onclick
    <label for="business">Welcome to Long Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="short_question">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Short Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="mcq">
    <label for="business">Welcome to MCQ Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="reasons">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Reasons Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="matching_questions">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Matching Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>  

-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your logic, you have:

```
if(this.value === "5"){
    $("#matching_questions").show();
} else {
    $("#long_question").hide();        // <==== Note
}
```

So even when `this.value` is `"1"`, eventually you'll go there and hide the `#long_question` element again.

I assume you meant `matching_questions`, not `long_question`:

```
if(this.value === "5"){
    $("#matching_questions").show();
} else {
    $("#matching_questions").hide();        // <==== Note change
}
```

Example:

```js
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === "1"){
        $("#long_question").show();
    } else {
        $("#long_question").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "2"){
        $("#short_question").show();
    } else {
        $("#short_question").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "3"){
        $("#mcq").show();
    } else {
        $("#mcq").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "4"){
        $("#reasons").show();
    } else {
        $("#reasons").hide();
    }
 if(this.value === "5"){
        $("#matching_questions").show();
    } else {
        $("#matching_questions").hide();
    }
 
});
```

```css
#long_question, #short_question, #mcq, #reasons, #matching_questions {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<select class="form-control" id='purpose' required>
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">Long Questions</option>
    <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
    <option value="3">MCQ</option>
    <option value="4">Reasons</option>
    <option value="5">Matching Questions</option>
</select>
</div>

 - End of Select Field Division
 - Following are the division which should be displayed on click event
<form id="long_question"> This is the long questions div
    <label for="business">Welcome to Long Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="short_question">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Short Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="mcq">
    <label for="business">Welcome to MCQ Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="reasons">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Reasons Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>
<form id="matching_questions">
    <label for="business">Welcome to Matching Questions Area</label>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
</form>  

-
```

---

Side note: You can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) rather than all those `if`/`else`s:

```
$("#long_question").toggle(this.value === "1");
```

Comment: Thank You So much  its works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Again Thank you Mr. @T.J. Crowder. and yes you are right there should be matching_questions